# Determine width of <td> based on width <td> below?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I was wondering if it is possible to determine the width of the  tag, based on the width of the  tag below.

I currently have this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This title is way too long and screws up my style</td>
    <td>Title2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image1.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image2.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image3.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anyway to scale the Title  tags based on the width of the images below?

Hope it is clear.

Comment: By scale do you mean reduce the `font-size`?

Comment: Is JavaScript/jQuery allowed (you didn't add it to your tags)?

Comment: Is it your objective to force the width of the `TD` elements to only be as wide as the `IMG` elements in the row beneath?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. To be more clear the images are gathered through a loop. See this for further clarification (wordpress function): http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/gallery/

Is there a way to gather the image width through the loop, for each image?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be considered a bit of a hack, but if you set the width of cells in the upper row to have a minimum acceptable value, the cells in the second row will expand the columns. Here's a sample:

```
 <style>
     tr.titles td {
         width: 1px;
     }
 </style>

<table>
  <tr class="titles">
    <td>This title is way too long and screws up my style</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image2"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So in this case it will be the image, that determines the width of the column, and the overall width will be equal to the image width.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That actually does work, but is there not a nicer way to accomplish this? To be more clear the images are gathered through a loop. See this for further clarification (wordpress function): http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/gallery/

Is there a way to gather the image width through the loop, for each image?
Thanks

Comment: if I understood correctly, it is the style="width:100px" on img element that you're concerned with. I think you can just omit the width and let the browser handle that automatically.

Comment: Nice, you want first row td to reduce width has like second row td ? This is it : remove first td width, let second td fit to inner image.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a way with jquery . 
check this code :

if this you table.Give an id to it .

```
<table id='mytable'>
  <tr>
    <td>This title is way too long and screws up my style</td>
    <td>Title2</td>
    <td>Title 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image1" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image2" /></td>
    <td><img src="http://domain.com/image3" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So in the script part

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable > tr > td').click(function () {
                 var width = $(this).next('td').children('img').prop('width');
                 $(this).prop('width',''+width+'px');
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However it does not seem to be working. The td of the title takes the whole width necessary....

Comment: See my comment under the topic for further clarification on my issue.. Thanks

Comment: i have added some code to get the with of the image . hope this works  . try it  .